# Is there any way I can Inject my Service class in a non Service annotated classes in NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection

This ABCService class perform some initialization on service startup

```
class ABCService {
     
   public init() : void {
     some stuff...
    }
export const service = new ABCService();
```

I am using this class as loader

```
import { MicroframeworkLoader, MicroframeworkSettings } from 'microframework-w3tec';
import { service } from '../ABCService';
export const serviceLoader: MicroframeworkLoader = (settings: MicroframeworkSettings | undefined) => {
    service.init();
};
```

I am using this serviceLoader in bootstrapMicroframework loaders of APP.ts file.

```
bootstrapMicroframework({
   
    loaders: [
        serviceLoader
    ],
}).then(() => ... )
.catch(error => log.error('Application is crashed: ' + error));
```

Now I have another Service class annotated with @Service

```
@Service()
export public class XYZService {

 constructor(private userRepository: UserRepository, private dependency2: Dependency2){
  
  }
    
   public doSomeThing(): Promise<any> {
     ....
     ....
   }
  }
```

I want to inject this XYZService class in ABCService with all dependencies in XYZService being injected by the container. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I got to know that It's possible to get an instance of a service class in a non service classes using typedi's

```
Container.get<ServiceClassType>(ServiceClassType);
```